# Craft on Heroku is not logging. How can I make it start?

Tags: logging

I don't have any logs appearing in `craft/storage/runtime/logs` (in fact I don't have anything at all in `craft/storage/runtime`.  I'm running Craft on Heroku.  I've tried setting post-install scripts in the `composer.json` file to run

```
chmod -R 774 craft/storage
```

but it doesn't change the permissions (they remain at 700).  We run Papertrail to collect logs from the dynos, but these only seem to include web requests - no application logging.  I've tried enabling `devMode`, but it makes no difference.

I'm trying to debug some issues we have with the application occasionally falling over, but without access to logs it's impossible - is there any way to make Craft start logging?  Just logging to stdout would be fine, as Papertrail would collect the logs. I can't find any configuration options, maybe I've missed them?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that redirects all of Craft log output to stderr that works on Heroku and Fortrabbit.

https://github.com/ostark/craft-stderr-logger